# Showing a curve is in a surface

Tags: curves

Given the following curve
$$\alpha(t)=(4sin(t),t,-4cos(t))$$
I gotta show it's in a surface.

I know
$$x^2(t)+y^{2}(t)+z^{2}(t)=16+t^{2}$$
but I'm not sure what can I do with it.

Comment: There are many surfaces that contain this curve. e.g. $x^2 + z^2 - 16 = 0$ and $x\cos(y) + z\sin(y) = 0$. You need to be more specific about what sort of surfaces you are locking for.

Comment: @achillehui my exercise just asks to show it's in a surface and then, to draw it. I thought about getting the cylinder made by 16+t^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a helix, clearly situated on the cylindrical surface with equation:

$$x^2+z^2=16$$